# I want to extract the .zip,.R formats or any other formats from a url and form a new column using R

Tags: r

I have the following type of urls in a data frame

```
https://ckd.upgrad.com/UpGrad/73ba5189-94fd-44aa-88d3-6b36aaa69b02/DDA1610095.zip
https://ckd.upgrad.com/UpGrad/0d507851-d102-4714-866c-348b0acf053f/DDA1610195.R
```

Also there are other types i.e other than .zip and .R in the url column

I want to form a column where I list the type of uploads such as .zip , .R or any other formats.I could achieve this using a `separate()` function from `tidyr` package but that brings up some unnecessary columns.

How can I do this using a `str_extract_all()` or a `grep` function, what is the pattern I should use ? Please explain the pattern you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `string_extract_all`

```
urls <- c(
    "https://ckd.upgrad.com/UpGrad/73ba5189-94fd-44aa-88d3-6b36aaa69b02/DDA1610095.zip", 
    "https://ckd.upgrad.com/UpGrad/0d507851-d102-4714-866c-348b0acf053f/DDA1610195.R")

library(stringr)
str_extract_all(urls, "\\.\\w+$")
#[[1]]
#[1] ".zip"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] ".R"
```

Using `gsub`

```
gsub("^.+(\\.\\w+)$", "\\1", urls)
#[1] ".zip" ".R"
```

Using `regexpr` with `regmatches`

```
regmatches(urls, regexpr("\\.\\w+$", urls))
#[1] ".zip" ".R"
```

`"\\.\\w+"` matches a full stop followed by at least one word character. `$` is the right string anchor.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tools);
fname = "https://ckd.upgrad.com/UpGrad/73ba5189-94fd-44aa-88d3- 
                                       6b36aaa69b02/DDA1610095.zip";

file_extension = file_ext(fname);
```

Comment: Thanks,easy to use.do you know how I can do the same using grep or str_extract_all() ?I am keen to know what pattern should be used for my learning purpose

Comment: Just type the function file_ext without calling it.

Comment: pos <- regexpr("\\.([[:alnum:]]+)$", x)